# ASP.NET webforms identity issue

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

We have a very strange issue with identity which even though it authenticates the users it keeps redirecting to the `/login` page.

As soon as we recycle the application pool the user can login without redirection issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: try using asp.net session state server, or turn on the session state service on windows, then tell your app to use that. With this, the recyling of app pool will affect the login state

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have issues, disabling the sessionState on the page level where you use the login (identity code) does the trick and sort outs this strange issue.

Basically just add this EnableSessionState="False" to your login page.

Comment: It would be better to share some code to make your answer more clear and understandable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).